# UnknownApiNameOrVersion from Google's My Business API (mybusiness)

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client, google-my-business-api

I'm using [Google's My Business API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest) via [Google's API Python Client Library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client).

Without further ado, here is a complete code example:

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from os.path import exists
from pprint import pprint
import os
import pickle

load_dotenv()

API_DEVELOPER_KEY = os.getenv('API_DEVELOPER_KEY')
API_SCOPE = os.getenv('API_SCOPE')
STORED_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS = os.getenv('STORED_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS')
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = os.getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')


def get_google_credentials(path=STORED_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS):
    '''Loads stored credentials. Gets and stores new credentials if necessary.'''
    if exists(path):
        pickle_in = open(path, 'rb')
        credentials = pickle.load(pickle_in)
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_file(
            GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_file=GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, scopes=API_SCOPE)
        flow.run_local_server()
        credentials = flow.credentials
        store_google_credentials(credentials)
    return credentials


def store_google_credentials(credentials, path=STORED_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS):
    '''Store credentials for future reuse to avoid authenticating every time.'''
    pickle_out = open(path, 'wb')
    pickle.dump(credentials, pickle_out)
    pickle_out.close()


def get_google_api_interface(credentials, service_name, service_version, service_discovery_url=None):
    '''Get a resource object with methods for interacting with Google's API.'''
    return build(service_name,
                 service_version,
                 credentials=credentials,
                 developerKey=API_DEVELOPER_KEY,
                 discoveryServiceUrl=service_discovery_url)


def extract_dict_key(dict, key):
    '''Utility to extract particular values from a dictionary by their key.'''
    return [d[key] for d in dict]


def transform_list_to_string(list, separator=' '):
    return separator.join(map(str, list))


def get_google_account_names():
    '''Get a list of all account names (unique ids).'''
    google = get_google_api_interface(
        get_google_credentials(),
        service_name='mybusinessaccountmanagement',
        service_version='v1',
        service_discovery_url='https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1')
    accounts = google.accounts().list().execute()
    return extract_dict_key(accounts['accounts'], 'name')


def get_google_store_reviews(account_name):
    '''Get all store reviews for a specific account from Google My Business.'''
    google = get_google_api_interface(
        get_google_credentials(),
        service_name='mybusiness',
        service_version='v4',
        service_discovery_url='https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4')
    return google.accounts().locations().batchGetReviews(account_name).execute()


account_names = get_google_account_names()

pprint(account_names)

first_account_name = account_names[0]

pprint(get_google_store_reviews(first_account_name))
```

And here is the contents of `.env`:

```
API_DEVELOPER_KEY = ********
API_SCOPE = https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage
STORED_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS = secrets/credentials.pickle
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = secrets/client_secrets.json
```

My function `get_google_account_names()` works fine and  returns the expected data:

```
['accounts/******************020',
 'accounts/******************098',
 'accounts/******************872',
 'accounts/******************021',
 'accounts/******************112']
```

I have tested and validated `get_google_credentials()` to ensure that `CLIENT_CREDENTIALS` and `API_DEVELOPER_KEY` are indeed loaded correctly and working.

Also, in `.env`, I'm setting the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the `client_secret.json` path, as required some methods in Google's Python Client Library.

My function `get_google_store_reviews()`, however, results in this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/my-project-dir/my-script.py", line 88, in <module>
    pprint(get_google_store_reviews())
  File "/my-project-dir/my-script.py", line 76, in get_google_store_reviews
    google = get_google_api_interface(
  File "/my-project-dir/my-script.py", line 46, in get_google_api_interface
    return build(service_name,
  File "/my-project-dir/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 131, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/my-project-dir/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 324, in build
    raise UnknownApiNameOrVersion("name: %s  version: %s" % (serviceName, version))
googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: mybusiness  version: v4
```

I have also tried v1 of the Discovery Document with the same result.

Does anyone know what's going on here? It seems like the API `mybusiness` is not discoverable via the Discovery Document provided by Google, but I'm not sure how to verify my suspicion.

Note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102807/getting-403-error-when-accessing-google-my-business-api-through-service-account) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57813182/issue-with-accessing-google-my-business-api-on-flask-app-using-o-auth) issue is related, but not exactly the same. The answers in those questions are old don't seem to be applicable anymore after recent changes by Google.

**Update:**

As a commenter pointed out, this API appears to be deprecated. That might explain the issues I'm having, however, [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/sunset-dates) states:

> "Deprecated indicates that the version of the API **will continue to function** […]"

Furthermore, notice that even though the top-level `accounts.locations` is marked as deprecated, some other the underlying methods (including `batchGetReviews`) are not.

See screenshot for more details:

[image: Google's Deprecation Dchedule Documentation]

This issue has also been [reported in GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/1735).

Comment: The client libraries are programmatically built from the [discovery doc](https://developers.google.com/discovery).  It the api is not in the discovery doc then its not part of Google apis and you cant use it with that library.

Comment: Most of the Google apis for my business were [Deprecation](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/sunset-dates)  as far as i can see

Comment: Thank you for the pointers, @DaImTo! I'm specifically trying to get all reviews for many store locations via ```accounts.locations.batchGetReviews``` (https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations/batchGetReviews) by following this and [this official guide from Google](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data#get_reviews_from_multiple_locations). I missed the fact that ```accounts.locations.*``` appears to be deprecated. The specific method ```batchGetReviews``` is not marked as deprecated. Very confusing and misleading docs.

Comment: accounts.locations.*  <-- Check the *  It normally means everything under that. Meaning all methods under accounts.locations.     accounts.locations.batchGetReviews falls under that.

Comment: Ah, my bad. There isn't actually a ```*``` in the deprecation message, I added it to indicate that it might be implied. I will update my question with some more info and a screenshot to show what I'm referring to.

Comment: I think you should cross post this [issue forum](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues)  UnknownApiNameOrVersion means its not being built by your library.  Ask over on their issue forum.   That being said they cant build it if it was removed from discovery services

Comment: Thanks again, @DaImTo! I have sent opened a support ticket with Google and also created [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/1735) as you suggested. I'm leaving a link here, just in case someone else stumbles upon the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

**Regarding the UnknownApiNameOrVersion error:**

If you open the discovery link you are using (https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4), you will see that it now only says

```
{
  "error": {
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Method not found.",
  "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

Try using this link instead: https://developers.google.com/static/my-business/samples/mybusiness_google_rest_v4p9.json

**Regarding correct method usage of the batchGetReviews method:**

The method will require a [request body containing a locationNames](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations/batchGetReviews#request-body) property.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that! I have now changed my function ``get_google_store_reviews(account_name)`` to get reviews for one account only so that I can call it successively for each account, however, the original problem (`UnknownApiNameOrVersion`) still remains.

Comment: @vpriesner This does not solves the problem, The issue is still the same.

Comment: @NageshSinghChauhan I updated my answer to reflect the API changes.

Comment: Thank you, it solves the issue but I face some problems with request = service.accounts().locations().reviews().updateReply(
        name=f'accounts/{account_id}/locations/{location_id}/reviews/{review_id}',
        body={'comment': reply_text}
    ).execute() //404 not found

Comment: Please create a separate question for questions regarding review replies, this is not related.